# Strange Problems with Strings in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am new to JAVA and found some of its concepts very irritating and no matter how hard I try I can not find suitable explanation for this behavior...of course there are wor around for these problems but still I want to know am I missing something very simple here or JAVA is like this???

1. I have a string array in one of my class A and  I want it to be filled through a method of another class B...so I create an object of class B into A and call the method B.xyz and equate it to the string arra but BOOM I can't do it....java throws a nullpointer exception..........I dont know why...

.

```
public class B{
    public void xyz() {
         String[] mystrings=new String[70];
         for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
             mystrings[i]=value;    
         return mystrings;
    }
}

public class A {
   public void abc() {

      B b=new B();
      String[] StringList;
      StringList=b.xyz();
      System.out.println(StringList.length);
   }
}
```

I have a similar code fragment now sadly the length of the StrinList becomes 70....if I want to print all the strings of this array I dont have any other way....remember even though the size of mystring is 70 in class B only 5 of its components are properly initialized........SO considering I am in class A and have no way to find out how many times did the for loop in B executed......how do I accurately loop through all the elements of StringList in A.........

PS: There are workarounds to solve this problem but I wanted to know why this happens,i.e, why the length attribute doesn't change according to the components initialized??

Comment: You probably don't want to "create an object of class B into A" but rather want a reference to the A object that is active.  For better help, consider posting code that is formatted so we can read it.

Comment: Your code does not compile. I am not sure how you were able to execute it. "String[] mystrings[70];" is not correct

Comment: Edited to remove pass by reference tag, you're not passing anything anywhere.

Comment: @fmucar: yes that was a typo edited the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need an array of length 5 then only initialize it as that size, e.g.:

```
public String[] xyz(String value) {
    String[] mystrings = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < mystrings.length; i++) {
        mystrings[i] = value;
    }
    return mystrings;
}
```

If you want an array that you can expand you should consider using [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead. E.g.:

```
public List<String> abc(String value) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        list.add(value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then you can get its size, add to it and print the elements like this:

```
List<String> list = abc("foo");
System.out.println(list.size());
list.add("bar");
for (String value : list) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You declared xyz as a method with return type `void` in class `B`. Presumably you want a signature that returns a string array, `public String[] xyz()`

Also you didn't declare the array correctly in B, the correct declaration is:

`String[] myStrings = new String[70];`

-- Dan

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] mystrings = new String[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at using List like ArrayList as this wraps arrays to make them easier to use.

```
String[] mystrings[70];
```

This creates an array or arrays. There are two `[]`

I suggest you try instead.

```
String[] mystrings = new String[5];
```